# CSS property specificity

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

```
1)  #divID input[type='text']
    {
       height:30px;
    }

2)  #divID .ClassName
    {
       height:40px;
    }
```

For a text box in a div, I have the above styles defined. 2 is more specific than 1, but the rendered height is 30px. How does it work?

Comment: If both selectors are meant to apply to the same element, then no inheritance is involved. Inheritance only works from a parent element to a child element, and even then `height` is not inherited by default anyway.

Comment: Not sure why you're being downvoted as I think this is a legitimate question.  Even if you knew the selector specificity you may not realize the effect of the `input` part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2 is not more specific than 1.  1 is actually more specific.

CSS selectors are divided into three levels (for the purposes of this discussion; there are actually more because of the `style` attribute and `!important`).

The ID selector `#` is at the highest level.

Classes and attributes `.ClassName`, `[type=text]`, `[id=x]` are on the second level as are pseudo-classes.

Elements and pseudo elements are on the lowest level.

Ties on one level move to the next level.  Both rulesets are tied for the ID and the class/attribute level (`.ClassName` and `[type=text]` are tied).

The first ruleset has an element as part of the selector, but the other has none.  Thus, the first ruleset wins on the lowest level.

http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity

Comment: `style` and `!important` are more of a cascading issue; specificity refers to selectors for the most part. In particular, `!important` is per-declaration allowing you to override one or more specific properties *only* without changing the selector. The CSS2.1 documentation doesn't make these distinctions very clear, but it does define well the order in which they should cascade anyway.